# Tridion Experience Manager & Static Implementation

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, session-preview, outbound-email

We have installed Tridion Experience Manager 2012. We will implement it for our dynamic web sites (based on Tridion CWA framework) but we are also investigating to use it in relation with our E-Marketing (Outbound E-mail) implementation.

Today our Outbound E-mail implementation is fully static. No Broker DB, mirror pages are directly published as HTML files on a web server (live or staging).

When we configure Experience Manager for these pages, **all works (Inline editing tags are correctly included and interpreted) except the Session Preview**.

Each time we edit a page, a warning message appears on the top of the window : "The preview for this page is not up to date". If we click on the button "Update the page preview" the message still appears and modifications are not displayed. If we publish modifications on the staging server then all is ok.

My questions:

- Is there a way to configure the Session Preview in this kind of
  implementation WITHOUT transforming the staging environment into a
  "dynamic implementation" (java or .net) ?
- According to the documentation, it seems that the only way to enable
  session preview is to configure a preview claimstore. Is there an
  alternative way (don't know. Maybe based on AJAX direct calls to the preview
  webservice for ex) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the basis of the content of [this question and answers](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/218/is-it-possible-to-use-experience-manager-session-preview-without-the-ambient-dat), I think the answer is no. You need the Ambient Data Framework, and thus a web application server (Java/.NET/oData webservice) for session preview. I don't know if an AJAX approach could work, as session preview could alter the entire HTML of the published page (for example if you changed the page template and all the component presentations), so I dont know how you are going to 'feed' this update into your existing HTML

Comment: Also, if you really don't want Session Preview you can turn it off. You get less awesome functionality, but it will still work -- you just have to wait for it to Publish the item before you see the changes.