# Abstracting the ambient data framework to a webservice

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, ambient-data-framework, session-preview

I have a DD4T site that we are trying to implement using a WCF service provider model so that the content delivery is separated from the website.

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1.

We have created a WCF service that exposes the DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1 methods. We also have created a Provider for DD4T that calls this webservice.

We are still in the POC stage of the project and we are looking in to other possible issues with this approach.

We have ran in to an issue with Session preview and the Ambient data framework needing to be included as a HTTP module of the website.

Is there a way to abstract the ambient data framework so that it can be called through a webservice so that we can maintain separation between the web application and Tridion content delivery.

Will Price has a question that he himself has answered:
[Is it possible to use Experience Manager Session Preview without the Ambient Data Framework?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/218/is-it-possible-to-use-experience-manager-session-preview-without-the-ambient-dat)

Looking at the answer it looks like this is possible to call the ADF through the CD webservice but this cannot merge the result of the broker DB and the session preview storage.

Has anyone managed to achieve this level of abstraction with a DD4T implementation ?

Comment: This is not the answer you're looking for... we have this on our roadmap, hope to bring it out soon (H1 2015 if all goes well). I know our pre-sales team did some magic on ADF with a REST service, but don't know details of it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Nuno. It is not a show stopper for us as we only need this on certain servers and not in production as we are only using it for experience manager.

Comment: There are some parts in this blog article that deal with having the CD Webservice running on a different webservice and forwardinf ADF claims, so you might get some pointers from there, not sure about XPM though
http://blog.addictivesoftware.net/smarttarget-render-engine-language-and-the-ambient-data-framework/

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no you cannot; ADF resides in your web application and relies on having direct access to the request object. Your solution approach essentially makes it impossible to use lots of extensions in an out-of-the-box manner (SmartTarget, Experience Manager, SDL Mobile, etc).

Long answer: yes you can... but you will have to do everything these extensions normally do in your own code; in essence as far as Tridion is concerned your DD4T WCF service "is your application" so if you can guarantee such things as session consistency (between the actual application and your DD4T WCF service), request header forwarding, etc it should in theory be possible to have your WCF service provide you with session preview content where applicable. There will be many potential problems to work around (such as ADF claim forwarding from the XPM editor to your application to DD4T WCF) but it should be possible...