# How can I pass the preview session token to a web service in Tridion 2011 SP1?

Tags: experience-manager, 2011-sp1, session-preview

In this ([Is it possible to use Experience Manager Session Preview without the Ambient Data Framework?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/218/is-it-possible-to-use-experience-manager-session-preview-without-the-ambient-dat)) post, Will Price explains how you can work with XPM if you host the ADF in a data service (which gets called by your web app) rather than in the web app itself.

The key is to pass a 'Preview Session Token' from the web app to the service. I have seen this working in 2013, where the token is contained in a cookie called "preview-session-token". But in 2011SP1, this cookie does not appear to be set. I do see a cookie 'TAFTrackingId' but I doubt if that is it.

How can I pass the preview session token to a web service in Tridion 2011 SP1?

Comment: From what I recall of Nuno's roadmap presentations, this feature came available as of 2013.  In 2011 you had to have the ADF and were limited to Java or .Net based website architecture if needing Session Preview.

Comment: Turned out it was a configuration problem on the CM side. Once that was solved, I received the preview-session-token cookie in the web application. There is NO difference between 2011 and 2013 in this respect.

Comment: Can you share what the CM config needed to be?

Answer (score 3):

It was actually a DNS issue: the CM could not reach the session preview webservice because the host name could not be resolved. Once we fixed that and restarted the CM, the session preview cookie showed up in our web app.